# Example For using QSettings to save QLineEdit text

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qsettings

Can I get a line of code that saves text of QLineedit and on restarting the app , it is retrieved ? 
Please help , its very important for my project …

Comment: Did you even tried it by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //read 
 QSettings settings("settingName");
 QString aValue=settings.value("aKey").toString();


 //write
 QSettings settings("settingName");
 QString somevalue=textedit.text();
 settings.setValue("aKey",somevalue);
```

Comment: Furthermore, the read can be in the ctor of your QMainWindow (or in general, QWidget) and the write in your reimplementation of QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*) in the QWidget or derivate.